# Why does refreshObject:mergeChanges: SegFault

Tags: ios, core-data, segmentation-fault

I have random crash I'm looking to understand deeper.  I have an NSManagedObject in that is created in a context that a childContext of our master context.
`childContextWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`

When I invoke

`managedObjectContext refreshObject:self mergeChanges:NO`

I get a seg fault,  only sometimes and I haven't reproduced it.  Does this mean that the object was deleted from the master context?  Can someone explain?

Comment: When are you calling it, and on which context, inside a perform block?

Comment: It's being called randomly,  on the child context.   It's not inside a perform block,  but it's on the thread that the child context was created on.

Comment: Thread doesn't matter, you need to use a perform block